# Entity Framework Core: many-to-many relationship with same entity

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to map many-to-many relationship with the same entity. The `User` entity has an `IList<User>` data field for `Contacts`, which stores users' contacts/friends information:

```
public class User : DomainModel
{
    public virtual IList<User> Contacts { get; protected set; }
    //irrelevant code omitted
}
```

When I try to use fluent API to map this many to many relationship, it gives me some trouble. Apparently, when I use `HasMany()` on the `user.Contacts` property, it has no `WithMany()` method to call next. The intellisense from Visual Studio only shows `WithOne()`, but not `WithMany()`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Contacts).WithMany() 
// gives compile time error: CS1061 'CollectionNavigationBuilder<User, User>' does not contain a definition for 'WithMany' and no extension method 'WithMany' accepting a first argument of type
```

So why does this happen? Is there anything I did wrong to map this many-to-many relationship?

Comment: You may take a look at this : https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many

Answer (score 27):

> So why does this happen? Is there anything I did wrong to map this
>   many-to-many relationship?

No, you didn't do anything wrong. [It's just not supported](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many). Current status [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368).

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the
>   join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a
>   many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join
>   table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

With EF-Core you should create the entity for the mapping table. Such as `UserContacts`. A complete example in the [docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many), as mentioned in the comments. I haven't actually tested the code below, but it should look something like this:

```
public class UserContacts
{
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int ContactId { get; set; } // In lack of better name.
    public virtual User Contact { get; set; }
}

public class User : DomainModel
{
    public List<UserContacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

And your `modelBuilder`.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserContacts>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Contact)
        .WithMany(p => p.Contacts)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ContactId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserContacts>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
        .WithMany(t => t.Contacts)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);
```

Comment: In the first modelBulder.Entity, should it be ".WithMany(p => p.Users)" instead of ".WithMany(p => p.Contacts)"?

Comment: @CarlosAdrián - I think not. Since its a reference to the same table. It is still a user which has several contacts. The contact is still a user.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Instead I found the following answer to a similar question that solved the many-to-many self-reference problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49219124/430742

Comment: @Jpsy Yes you are correct. Existing answer was not correct. Existing answer would only works for the many to many between two different types not for the same type. I have modified the answer. Now it will work for the same type.

Comment: @TanvirArjel: Sorry, I don't see your edit yet. Did you save your changes correctly? Currently the last edit of this answer is from Feb 25'17.

Comment: @Jpsy smoksnes didn't approve my modification to his  answer. I have posted it as a separate answer. Please check it.