# How to join information whose relationship is repeated between two tables using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-core

I have a double relationship between the Person and PersonCompany tables where a Person can be any individual or legal person or a Person who is registered as a Company.
When I need to fetch a Person (Person table) with Id 2 from the bank, the EF should return the People and PersonsCompany that relate to the Person table, but this is not happening ... I believe the problem occurs because the Person and PersonCompany properties are from same type as Person. This makes EF understand that they are the same thing and returns values ​​that do not match the related PersonCompany.

Do I have to do some sort of "Select" within the PersonsCompan navigation property? Does anyone know how to help me?

[image]

```html
//Get value of table Person
public Pessoa GetById(int id)
        {


            return DbSet
                .Include(pe => pe.Persons)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Person)
                .Include(pe => pe.PersonsCompany)
                    .ThenInclude(pe => pe.PersonCmpany)

                //(... other related tables )

                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == id);
                
         }
```

```js
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PersonEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("PersonEntity");

            builder.HasKey(pg => new { pg.PersonId, pg.PersonType});

            builder
               .HasOne(p => p.Person)
               .WithMany(pg => pg.Persons)
               .HasForeignKey(pg => pg.PersonId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            builder.Property(pg => pg.PersonId)
               .HasColumnName("PersonId")
               .HasColumnType("integer")
               .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(pg => pg.PersonType)
               .HasColumnName("PersonTypeId")
               .HasColumnType("integer")
               .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(pg => pg.IdGeneral)
               .HasColumnName("IdGeneral")
               .HasColumnType("integer")
               .IsRequired();

            builder
              .HasOne(f => f.PersonCompany)
              .WithMany(pg => pg.PersonsCompany)
              .HasForeignKey(pg => pg.PersonCompanyId)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

            builder.Property(pg => pg.PersonCompanyId)
               .HasColumnName("PersonCompanyId")
               .HasColumnType("integer")
               .IsRequired();
           
        }
```

```js
 public class Person : Entity
 {
 public virtual ICollection<PersonEntity> Persons { get; private set; }
 public virtual ICollection<PersonEntity> PersonsCompany { get; private set; }
 }
```

```js
 public class PersonEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public int PersonId { get; private set; }
        public int PersonCompanyId { get; private set; }

        public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; private set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; private set; }
        public virtual Person PersonCompany { get; private set; }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the entity classes in question and relevant fluent configuration if any.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem is similar to [Entity Framework Core: many-to-many self referencing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214748/entity-framework-core-many-to-many-self-referencing-relationship), so is the solution.

The confusion in your case comes from the collection navigation property names and their mappings to the reference navigation properties:

`Person.Persons` -> `PersonEntity.Person`

and

`Person.PersonsCompany` -> `PersonEntity.PersonCompany`

You should probably rename them like this:

`Person.PersonCompanies` -> `PersonEntity.Person`

and

`Person.CompanyPersons` -> `PersonEntity.PersonCompany`

so the other reference navigation property represents the intended link.

E.g.

*Model:*

```
public class Person : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<PersonEntity> PersonCompanies { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonEntity> CompanyPersons { get; private set; }
}
```

*Relationship configuration:*

```
builder
   .HasOne(p => p.Person)
   .WithMany(pg => pg.PersonCompanies)
   .HasForeignKey(pg => pg.PersonId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

builder
  .HasOne(f => f.PersonCompany)
  .WithMany(pg => pg.CompanyPersons)
  .HasForeignKey(pg => pg.PersonCompanyId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

*Usage:*

```
.Include(p => p.PersonCompanies)
    .ThenInclude(pe => pe.PersonCompany)
.Include(p => p.CompanyPersons)
    .ThenInclude(pe => pe.Person)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ivan Stoev! Now I have another problem with the return of the GetById () method. If I get a Person with Id = 2 and need to return all PersonEntities related to Person he should bring them, but he gets lost and returns a list of PersonEntities where PersonCompanies with Id = 2 ... It seems like he is confused with Person

Comment: It seems that I need to modify the method where the Includes () are so it does not mess with the Person and PersonCompany navigation properties.