# EFCore Many/One to Many relationship of the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to set up a realationship between an object and versions of the same object. I am using EFCore and its saving the ID from one of the objects into both fields.

My objects are as follows:

```
public class Workflow
{
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; } = new List<Workflow>();

    public int InternalSequence { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<WorkflowVersionLink> VersionLinks { get; set; } = new List<WorkflowVersionLink>();
}



public class WorkflowVersionLink
{
    public int WorkflowVersionLinkId { get; set; }

    public int? IsVersionOfId { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow IsVersionOf { get; set; }

    public int? VersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow Version { get; set; }

    public bool IsLive { get; set; }
}
```

And I am  setting up the OnModelCreating as follows:

```
//All of my attempts have used this:
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
.HasKey(t => new { t.IsVersionOfId, t.VersionId });



//Attempt one: No manual configuration



//Attempt two:
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
  .HasOne(lk => lk.Version)
  .WithMany(wf => wf.VersionLinks)
  .HasForeignKey(lk => lk.VersionId);



//Attempt three (following info from SO):
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
  .HasOne(lk => lk.IsVersionOf)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(lk => lk.IsVersionOfId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
  .HasOne(lk => lk.Version)
  .WithMany(wf => wf.VersionLinks)
  .HasForeignKey(lk => lk.VersionId);
```

I have already tried the approach here:
[Many-to-many self referencing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214748/many-to-many-self-referencing-relationship/49219124#49219124) & the other approaches mentioned above.

I am open to changing to structure, before all of this I didn't use the WorkflowVersionLink Object, and just had a List Versions, however this failed also because I already have a list of child workflows (which I need to keep)

As you can see, I have attempted to fix this issue myself, but I am now stuck and decided to turn to StackOverflow.

You can see the database result here: (I am 100% sure I added two brand new objects that didnt have IDs each time I ran the code)
[database result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sor9r.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use `WorkflowVersionLinkId`  as the key and just add a Unique constraint on the `t.IsVersionOfId, t.VersionId`

Comment: I'm Assuming the link to the WorkflowVersionLink object is the issue.

Comment: if you are using no standard POCO Id should specific it with builder.Entity<model>().HasKey(x => x.[keyproperty]);

Comment: @RichardHubley Im not sure what you mean

Comment: @CarlosCocom I already do that don't i?

Comment: I have added a imgur image of the data it saves

Comment: *I have attempted to fix this issue myself* -- But, what's the issue? You should show the code that contains "the issue" and explain where/why it goes wrong. Also, show the "database result" in text please. I can think of a couple of ways to get that result, but, basically, we need to see your code in order to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would be extra sure you are creating new objects for Version and isVersionOf in your WorkflowVersionLink object. If you are trying to make a copy of one, you may be referencing the same object by mistake.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
.HasKey(t => t.WorkflowVersionLinkId );


modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
  .HasOne(lk => lk.Version)
  .WithMany(wf => wf.VersionLinks)
  .HasForeignKey(lk => lk.VersionId);

modelBuilder.Entity<WorkflowVersionLink>()
.HasOne(lk => lk.IsVersionOf)
.HasForeignKey(lk => lk.IsVersionOfId)
```

You may still need to add constraints to keep your database clean