# EF Core one-to-many or many-to-many ? users<-->friends

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm going to implement a user-friends module in my project.

Let's say I have 2 simple classes **:**

```
public class User
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And FriendShip class (which has a relation between user) :

```
public class FriendShip
{
    int User1Id { get; set; }
    int User2Id { get; set; }
    int Status  { get; set; }
}
```

Status type is `Enum`

Logic for these 2 classes **:**

- When first user invite second user to his friendship-list, there should be 2 objects created in the database

```
user1Id: 1,
user2Id: 2,
Status: 1, (where 1 means 'invited')
```

---

```
user1Id: 2,
user2Id: 1,
Status: 0,    (where 0 means 'nonaccepted')
```

- When second user accepts, these 2 status will be updated by value 3 (where means 'friendship' or something like that - but forget about logic now.

I don't know how can I design the database.

It will be one-to-many, like one user can have many relationships to other-users ?

The private key must be 2 foreign key : user1, user2

The problem is that these 2 foreign keys goes to one table (Users)

I tried something like this **:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(x => x.UsersFriendships)
    .WithOne(x => x.User2)

modelBuilder.Entity<UsersFriendship>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Users)
    .WithOne(x => x.UsersFriendships)
```

But it doesn't make sense, I can't do the second statement

```
.WithOne(x => x.userFriendships)
```

---

The simplest way is to type in model builder **:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersFriendship>()
   .HasKey(x => new { x.User1Id, x.User2Id });
```

UserFriendship class :

```
public class UsersFriendship 
{
    [ForeignKey("User1Id")]
    public User User1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User2Id")]
    public User User2 { get; set; }

    public int User1Id { get; set; }
    
    public int User2Id { get; set; }
    
    public RelationStatus RelationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

But from now, I can't navigate from User entity to his friends (like `User.Friendship`)

and when I add navigation property to User class **:**

```
public virtual List<UsersFriendship> UsersFriendships { get; set; }
```

Database will four fields : user1Id, user2Id, status, userId

the latest field comes from user class (UsersFriendships field) <-- and I don't want this field on my database!

Comment: by the way, I am assuming your friends are not ships (put "ship" in lowercase in `class Friendship`)

Comment: [Дмитрий Данилов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13720596/Дмитрий-Данилов) said in an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64766627/12695027) that "This solution did not work for me. Instead I found the following answer to a similar question that solved the many-to-many self-reference problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49219124/430742"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find one example in the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many.

So for your case:

```
namespace foo
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // List of users who initiated the "friendship"
        public virtual List<Friendship> Inviters { get; set; }
        // List of users who where invited to the "friendship"
        public virtual List<Friendship> Invitees { get; set; }
    }

    public class Friendship
    {
        public int User1Id { get; set; }
        public User User1 { get; set; }
        public int User2Id { get; set; }
        public User User2 { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                .HasKey(fs => new { fs.User1Id, fs.User2Id, fs.Status });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                .HasOne(fs => fs.User1)
                .WithMany(u => u.Inviters)
                .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User1Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>()
                .HasOne(fs => fs.User2)
                .WithMany(u => u.Invitees)
                .HasForeignKey(fs => fs.User2Id);
        }
    }
}
```

For both your `user1` and `user2` foreign keys, you also need to register different virtual lists to distinguish the two `withMany` inverse mappings in your model builder. If you don't want to define these lists, the just leave the `.WithMany()` blank. This creates the model without explicit navigation properties for user friendships. You can still use EF Core to handle the database relationships, but you won't have the convenience of direct navigation properties for user friendships in your code.

In any case, if you later want to retrieve all "friendships" where the user is either referenced with `User2Id` or `User2Id` you can use e.g. this:

```
context.Friendships
    .Where(f => f.User1Id == userId || f.User2Id == userId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: are you sure? I updated my example to match your problem. please check again.

Comment: i'm sorry but in meantime i have updated my post. now your example do same thinks like mine with attributes i think. but i dont know what should i do to have navigation property in Userclass, but to don't have additional field in database

Comment: Does not work. You need  two public virtual List<UsersFriendship>