# How to implement friendship structure with EFCore 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know my question might be duplicated but I didn't find any answer that completely solves this question.
I just want to implement a friendship structure with EFCore, I tried `Self Many-To-Many` relationship like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person>? Friends { get; set; }
}
```

but didn't work.
I also tried to add another table just for storing friendships like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonFriend>? Friends { get; set; }
}


public class PersonFriend
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Friend { get; set; }

    public int FriendId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this is that I should insert 2 rows for each relationship and I think this is not standard at all, I think this method will decrease performance and break clean coding rules. Is there any other solution to implement this situation without inserting more than 1 row for each relationship?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a specialist in this area, but AFAIK a relational table structure doesn't work well for this kind of information. You should maybe take a look at a graph table working with vertices and edges.

Comment: "I tried Self Many-To-Many... but didn't work" - can you elaborate on what didn't work?

Comment: @Xerillio Because with doing that, EF will create a column named 'PersonId', And that's a kind of foreign key or something like that, And there can't be more than one value in that column, so each person can be friend with just one other person

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, it is not possible to have a single friendship list `Friends`  in entity `Person`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247977/2484903. In short: You need a list of invited friends and a second collection of friends that invited you.

This is necessary because EF Core 6 cannot link multiple relations to `ICollection<Person>? Friends`.