# EF Core many to many of same object get error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

My situation is that I have a system which contain invoices and for each invoice I can create a receipt.

The relationship is many to many because I can produce a few receipts for each invoice, and also when I create the receipt I can relate it to few invoices.

I have the following two classes: `Document` which represent the invoice or receipt, and `DocumentOffset` which associates between the documents.

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? DocumentKind { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long DocumentNum { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? EntityID { get; set; }
    public double TaxDeduction { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public double SumBeforeDiscount
    {
        get
        {
            return Document2List.Sum(x => x.Sum);
        }
    }

    public double DiscountPercent { get; set; }

    public double DiscountValue 
    { 
        get
        {
            return SumBeforeDiscount * DiscountPercent / 100;
        }
    }

    public double SumBeforeTax 
    {
        get
        {
            return SumBeforeDiscount - DiscountValue;
        }
    }

    public int TaxPercent { get; set; } = 17;
    public double TaxValue 
    {
        get
        {
            return SumBeforeTax * TaxPercent / 100;
        }
    }

    public double Sum 
    {
        get
        {
            if(DocumentKind == (int)Enums.DocumentKind.eDocumentKind.Reciept || DocumentKind == (int)Enums.DocumentKind.eDocumentKind.SupplierReciept)
            {
                return Document3List.Sum(x => x.Sum).Value;
            }

            return SumBeforeTax + TaxValue;
        }
    }

    public double Paid 
    {
        get
        {
            return Document3List.Where(x => x.Sum.HasValue).Sum(x => x.Sum.Value);
        }
    }

    public double Balance 
    {
        get
        {
            return Sum - Paid;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Details { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime? Expire { get; set; }
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }

    public List<Document2> Document2List { get; set; } = new List<Document2>(); // Document items
    public List<Document3> Document3List { get; set; } = new List<Document3>(); // Document payments when invoice and receipt produced in the same document
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DocumentOffset> DocumentOffsets { get; set; } //this property
}
```

and

```
public class DocumentOffset
{
    public int DocumentID { get; set; } //FK
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public int RelatedDocumentID { get; set; } //FK
    public Document RelatedDocument { get; set; }
    public double Sum { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<MissionCardWorker>().HasKey(x => new { x.MissionCardId, x.WorkerId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<MissionCardItems>().HasKey(x => new { x.MissionCardId, x.ItemId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<MissionCardMission>().HasKey(x => new { x.MissionCardId, x.MissionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentOffset>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Document)
            .WithMany(x => x.DocumentOffsets)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RelatedDocumentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentOffset>()
            .HasOne(x => x.RelatedDocument)
            .WithMany(x => x.DocumentOffsets)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentID);
 }
```

When I try to add a migration I get the following error :

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Document.DocumentOffsets' and 'DocumentOffset.RelatedDocument', because there already is a relationship between 'Document.DocumentOffsets' and 'DocumentOffset.Document'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

What should I do resolve that?

Thanks :)

Comment: `Document`, `Document2`, `Document3`, .... I don't think you've sanitised your example very well... But you need two navigation properties; `ICollection<DocumentOffset> Children ... ICollection<DocumentOffset> Parents `

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I added a description to document2,document3.
I didn't understand how this answer solve my the presented error.

Comment: `List<Document2>`, `List<Document3>` ? These classes don't exists.

Comment: What if you create a second property DocumentOffsetsRelated and use this as the second navigation property?

Comment: Looks like your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214748/many-to-many-self-referencing-relationship

Comment: @Klamsi You're right , I wanted only 1 property but it looks like it's not possible so I changed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for a many-to-many join you'd follow a pattern like;

```cs
public class Parent{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Join> Join { get; set; }
}
public class Join{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
   public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
   public virtual Child Child { get; set; }

}
public class Child{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Join> Join { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Join>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.Join)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Join>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Child)
            .WithMany(x => x.Join)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildId);
```

But in your case you're trying to merge `Parent` and `Child` into the same type. You still need the same number of foreign keys and Navigation properties, but of course they'll all need to be unique.

```cs
public class Document{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<DocumentOffset> Parents { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<DocumentOffset> Children { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentOffset{
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
   public virtual Document Parent { get; set; }
   public virtual Document Child { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentOffset>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentOffset>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Child)
            .WithMany(x => x.Parents)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildId);
```

Comment: I changed my code so it will use 2 properties, that solved my problem.
Thanks :)