# Self-Referencing In Many-To-Many with Cascades

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

So I have a simple many to many relationship like below, and I have **manually** added `onUpdate: ReferantialAction.Cascade` on the foreign key part, and when I update my entitiy with a simple `SqlCommand` I can **successfully** update my entity.

```
public class Machine
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<MachinePart> MachineParts { get; set; }
}

public class Part 
{
   public string No { get; set; }
   public string Name { get set; }
  
   public List<MachinePart> MachineParts { get; set; }
}

public class MachinePart
{
    public string MachineNo { get; set; }
    public Machine Machine { get; set; }

    public string PartNo { get; set; }
    public Part Part { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
builder.Entity<MachinePart>().HasKey(i => new { i.MachineNo, i.PartNo });
```

**Migration**

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_MachineParts_Machines_MachineNo",
                table: "MachineParts",
                column: "MachineNo",
                principalTable: "Machines",
                principalColumn: "No",
                onUpdate: ReferentialAction.Cascade,
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

But now I have to cretae a **SELF REFERENCING MANY TO MANY TABLE** which can be a cascade relation,

```
public class MachineRelation
{
    public string MachineNo { get; set; }
    public Machine Machine { get; set; }

    public string ReferencedMachineNo { get; set; }
    public Machine ReferencedMachine { get; set; }
}
```

When I manually add
`onUpdate: ReferantialAction.Cascade` &&
`onDelete: ReferantialAction.Cascade`

I get cascade exception =>
**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_AssemblyRevisions_Assemblies_RevisionedAssemblyNo' on table 'AssemblyRevisions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.**

Comment: Well, this is known limitation of SqlServer (you can find many posts here by searching SO for "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"). The solution is always one and the same - turn the cascade delete off for at least one of the relationship and handle principal record deletion either manually or via database trigger. EF Core won't help in that regard, except if you specify the newer `ClientCascade` option for `.OnDelete`. In which case you should eagerly load the principal along with dependents before deleting it.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanations and for onUpdate cascades, how can I manage the cascade updates with EFCore, same as the onDelete?

Comment: Negative, as I wrote in another comment, EF Core does not support cascade updates through entity model.