# EF Core - Map property collection of same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to define an (EF Core, code first) entity that has a list of associates of the same type

```
public class Entity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Entity> Associates { get; set; }
}
```

The associates have no knowledge of the entity to which it belongs.

I am struggling to figure out how to map this (fluently)

Comment: It's already mapped by convention, what else do you want to map? For fluent APIs, see [Relationships - Manual Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration).

Comment: problem is that above results in a FK being added to the table, that results in the Associate having to know of the "parent".

The idea is to be able to associate as follows:

Entity1 -> { Entity2, Entity3 }

Entity2 -> {Entity4 }

if there is a FK on the table, it links it to one single parent

Comment: This actually provides my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771808/entity-framework-core-many-to-many-relationship-with-same-entity/39772091

Comment: So you are looking for many-to-many. Unfortunately the answer to the question from your link is wrong, you can see the correct solution here  [Many-to-many self referencing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214748/many-to-many-self-referencing-relationship)